# ifelse error when dealing with integer variable in R

Tags: r, if-statement, integer

I'm currently doing a very simple ifelse on an integer variable. But I'm getting the following error.

[image]

Note that "avg_col_f_score" is the variable I'm trying to create.

I've tried googling the problem but was unsuccessful. Any help/advice would be wonderful. Thanks!

Please see the following code.

```
ohyeah = as.data.frame(
  clust_df_full %>% 
    full_join(select(colleague_clust_df, c("employee_id", "colleague_cluster")),
              by = "employee_id") %>% 
    full_join(select(mgr_clust_df, c("employee_id", "mgr_cluster")),
              by = "employee_id") %>% 
    full_join(select(self_clust_df, c("employee_id", "self_cluster")),
              by = "employee_id") %>% 
    full_join(select(promo_clust_df, c("employee_id", "promo_cluster")),
              by = "employee_id") %>% 
    filter(nchar(employee_id) <= 10) %>% 
    
    left_join(colleague_clusters_summary,
              by = c("colleague_cluster" = "Cluster")
    ) %>% 
    select(-"Size") %>% 
    
    rename(avg_col_f1 = col_f1.y,
           avg_col_f2 = col_f2.y,
           avg_col_f3 = col_f3.y,
           avg_col_f4 = col_f4.y,
           avg_col_f5 = col_f5.y
           ) %>% 
    
    mutate(avg_col_f_score = ifelse(colleague_cluster == 1,
                                    avg_col_f1,
                                    ifelse(colleague_cluster == 2,
                                           avg_col_f2,
                                           ifelse(colleague_cluster == 3,
                                                  avg_col_f3,
                                                  ifelse(colleague_clust == 4,
                                                         avg_col_f4,
                                                         ifelse(colleague_cluster == 5,
                                                                avg_col_f5, NA)
                                                         )
                                                  )
                                           )
                                    )
           )
)
```

Comment: Please add sample data and code that we can copy & paste to reproduce the error you're seeing. Otherwise this is a guessing game.

Comment: Your current code, as _text_, would be very helpful here.

Comment: Sorry guys.. I was in a rush... I'll update the question!

Comment: Also, let me tell you about `case_when`. It won't fix your problem, but it's so much nicer than nested `if_else`. `case_when(colleague_cluster == 1 ~ avg_col_f1, colleague_cluster == 2 ~ avg_col_f2, colleague_cluster == 3 ~ ...)`

Comment: As to your problem, at least one of the columns in in your `if_else`s is a `list` column. Check the column classes. Make sure they're all the same class--probably they should be `numeric` looking at your error--and your problem should go away.

Answer (score 0):

Try with dyplr::rename() or eliminate NA at final of if_else() replace it with "" without space.